# During end battle of Rogue One, why did Bodhi try so hard to establish comms with the Alliance Fleet just to tell them something they already knew?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

During the Battle of Scarif, why did Bodhi Rook and the rest of the company on the ground desperately try to contact the Alliance Fleet, just to tell them something they already knew? Surely the Alliance Fleet above the shield gate already knew they had to destroy it as that was going be the only way to receive the data. If they weren't trying to destroy the shield gate from the start, what else were they doing up there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is addressed in the scene where Cassian Andor speaks to the pilot Bodhi.

> **Cassian:** *Listen to me. The Rebel fleet is out there. You've got to tell them to blow a hole in the shield-gate so we can transmit the
>   plans*

Since the plans are too high density to be transmitted over normal audio channels, the shield needs to be down and the Rebels need to have a high gain receiver pointed toward the planet in order to receive the plans via radio since their chances of getting off the planet at this point are essentially zero.

> **K-2SO:** *We could transmit the plans to the Rebel Fleet. We'd have to get a signal out to tell them it's coming*

If the fleet simply brings down the shield (expecting the ground forces to escape) that won't do any good.

> **K-2SO:** *There's fighting on the beach. They've locked down the base.*

Comment: Ok thanks for the response, do you think the Alliance knew the shield had to be destroyed in order to receive the plans? Or that it was news to them when Bodhi told them?

Comment: @DaveWalters - As far as they were aware, they needed to breach the shield in order to give ground support to the (Rogue One) insertion team so that they could steal the plans and fall back to space. They didn't (and couldn't) know that the team were trapped and would want to transmit the plans.

Comment: Would you say after the Alliance received the message from Bodhi, they decided to slightly change their plans and do a riskier all-out attack on the shield gate (like ramming a Hammerhead Corvette into a Destroyer)?

Comment: @DaveWalters - Yes, that's a very fair assessment. *"He heard voices in the background—bridge officers, maybe, debating how to respond. Bodhi powered through. “You have to get in position, get ready to receive. And you have to take down the shield gate. It’s the only way to get through!”
For an achingly long time, there was no answer.
“Copy you, Rogue One,” the voice finally said. “We’ll get it done.” Then, directed not to Bodhi but to someone else on the bridge: “Call in a Hammerhead corvette. I have an idea."* - Rogue One: Novelisation

Comment: Would you also say that the reason the Alliance didn't do an all-out attack from the start was because they weren't sure that Jyn and the company on the ground were even still alive? So that it wasn't worth the risk. Also why didn't the Alliance have their high gain receiver pointing down to the planet anyway?

Comment: @DaveWalters - You'd have to ask the Rebel commander that one. The original misson was to simply provide cover for the strike team.

Answer (score 5):

Bodhi didn't know they were there to destroy the shield gate, and that wasn't the only thing they needed to know. He was telling them they needed to destroy the shield gate in order to receive the transmission regarding the plans.  They also needed to be ready to receive the plans since it would be a large transfer and will be on a specific frequency.

There may have been parts of the conversation we didn't hear, and there may have been a part where the Admiral tells Bodhi what specific frequency to broadcast the transmission so that his ship gets the plans.

Answer (score 0):

(1)

> Surely the Alliance Fleet above the shield gate already knew they had to destroy it as that was going be the only way to receive the data.

Maybe they did, maybe they didn't. Some communication was obviously possible through the closed shield, though the Death Star data was too much to transmit.

> **Jyn:** We could transmit the plans to the rebel fleet. We'd have to get a signal out to tell them it's coming.
>
> **Cassian:** It's the size of the data files. That's the problem. They'll never get through. Someone has to take that shield gate down.

(2)

There was no prior coordination of plans, and the Rebel fleet was getting hit hard. They'd tried to destroy the gate already. They had no idea what the ground situation was, or even if anyone was still alive. They could have chosen any number of possible strategies: engage the enemy fleet harder, cut their losses and retreat, try to delay the battle, etc.

Thanks to the communication with Rogue One, they knew that victory would follow seconds after the shield gate was destroyed. They focused anew on this objective, prepared to received the transmission, and narrowly escape d with the Death Star designs.